# Capacitive reactance related to frequency

Tags: capacitor, ac, reactance

Why does capacitive reactance decrease with the increase of the frequency of the applied signal?

It is easy to prove why capacitive reactance decreases with increased capacitance. The more we increase the capacitance of a capacitor -> for the same charge at the plates of the capacitor we get less voltage which resists current from the AC source.

But why is reactance decreased with the increase of the frequency of the applied signal?

Comment: Another way we look at reactive power supplies is that current increases with frequency and/or capacitance. HF noise will go through the capacitor as if it was a short, so often a series resistor and inductor limit HF currents.

Comment: Errm.  If you've proved that the reactance increases as the frequency drops, then you've also proven that it increases as the frequency rises.

Comment: How do I prove that? I need help.

Comment: Start by examining the extremes. At zero frequency (DC) the capacitor is an open circuit, i.e. infinite impedance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The more we increase the capacitance of a capacitor -> for the same charge at the plates of the capacitor we get less voltage which resists current from the AC source.

First, let's look at how the capacitive reactance is obtained.

The relationship between electrical charge and current is:

$$
dq = i\ dt
$$

where \$q\$ is the electrical charge, \$i\$ is the current and \$t\$ is the time.

The change of electrical charge stored by the capacitor is:

$$
dq = C\ dV
$$

where \$C\$ is the capacitance and \$V\$ is the voltage across the capacitor.

From these two equations, we obtain the famous capacitor current-voltage relationship:

$$
i\ dt = C\ dV \\
\Rightarrow i_C = C \ \frac{dV_C}{dt}
$$

We can replace \$d/dt\$ with \$j\omega\$ (or \$2\pi f\$), so finally we obtain:
$$
i_C = V_C \ j\omega\ C \\
\Rightarrow V_C = i_C \ \frac{1}{j\omega \ C}
$$

The impedance of the capacitor is

$$
Z_C=\frac{i_C}{V_C}=\frac{1}{j\omega \ C}=\frac{1}{j\ 2\pi f \ C}
$$

and the capacitive reactance is the magnitude of the impedance:

$$
X_C=|Z_C|=\frac{1}{2\pi f \ C}
$$

So,

- the higher the frequency, the lower the capacitive reactance
- the higher the capacitance, the lower the capacitive reactance

Comment: I am looking for the intuition behind the formula and not just the math but anyway thanks.

Comment: +1 for explaining reactance is the magnitude of its impedance.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the RC network above, in the transient state, capacitive reactance is hard to define in the time domain because there are multiple sinusoids present in the signal. Therefore the frequency domain impedance response of the network needs to be analysed, specifically the ratio of impedances giving the output potential of the network, which is known as the transfer function, or 'the frequency response', and an inverse Laplace transform can be performed to give the time domain transient and steady state response. It is assumed that the output is terminated with a resistive load R<sub>L</sub>.

The transfer function of the system is:

$$ H(\omega) = \frac{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_L} + j\omega C}} {\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_L} + j\omega C} + R} $$

$$ H(s) = \frac{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_L} + sC}} {\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_L} + sC} + R} $$

$$V_o(s) = V_i(s) H(s) $$

The output signal in this case is the same as the capacitor response:

$$V_o(t) = V_c(t) = {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\{V_i(s) H(s)\}}  $$

The impulse response of the network is the output signal when the input signal is an impulse:

$$h(t) = {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\{V_i(s)H(s)\}} = {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\{{\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}\{\delta(t)\}} H(s)\}} = {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\{1H(s)\}} = \frac{1}{RC} e^{-\frac{t(R_L+R)}{R_LRC}} u(t) $$

Where u(t) is the heaviside step function, to indicate t is greater than or equal to zero, which is the output of the inverse Laplace, and indicates that it is a causal system.

The output signal is also equal to the convolution of the impulse response with the input signal:

$$ {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\{V_i(s)H(s)\}} =  {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\{V_i(s)\}}* {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\{H(s)\}}=V_i(t) *h(t) =\int^{t}_{0} h(t-\tau)V_i(\tau) ~d\tau$$

The impulse response of an RC circuit:

$$\lim_{R_L \to \infty} (h(t)) = \frac{1}{RC} e^{-\frac{t}{RC}} u(t) $$

The capacitor impulse current must be:

$$I_c(t) = C\frac{dV_o(t)}{dt} = C\frac{dh(t)}{dt} \equiv  {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\left\{H(s)\frac{1}{X_c(s)}\right\}};~ X_c(s) = \frac{1}{sC}$$

The output impulse current must be :

$$I_o(t) = {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\left\{H(s)\frac{1}{R_L}\right\}} = \frac{h(t)}{R_L} $$

By KVL, the impulse response of the resistor must be:

$$V_R(t) = V_i(t) - V_o(t)$$

$$h_R(t) = \delta (t) - h(t)$$

Indeed:

$$h_R(t) ={\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\{H_R(s)\}}  $$
$$ = \delta(t)u(t) - h(t)$$
$$ = \delta(t) - h(t)$$

$$ H_R(s) = \frac{R} {\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_L} + sC} + R} $$

The current over the resistor is (the inverse laplace of the input voltage multiplied by the transfer function that gives the potential division over the resistor, divided by the resistance that the potential is over):

$$I_R(t) = {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\left\{H_R(s)\frac{V_i(s)}{R}\right\}}  $$

If V<sub>i</sub> is an impulse then

$$I_R(t) = {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\left\{H_R(s)\frac{1}{R}\right\}} = {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\left\{\frac{V_i(s)}{Z_{total}(s)}\right\}}  $$
$$ = \frac{h_R(t)}{R}$$

We can see that:

$$I_R(t) = I_c(t) + I_o(t) = C\frac{dh(t)}{dt} + \frac{h(t)}{R_L} $$
$$= \frac{\delta(t)}{R} + \frac{(-R_L-R) h(t)}{R_LR} + \frac{h(t)}{R_L}$$
$$= \frac{\delta(t)}{R} - \frac{h(t)}{R} \equiv \frac{h_R(t)}{R}$$

The unit step response (V<sub>i</sub>(t) = u(t)) of the RC network is (the step response of the capacitor):

$${\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\left\{H(s)V_i(s)\right\}} $$
$$=\int^{t}_{0} h(t-\tau)V_i(t) ~d\tau$$
$$=\int^{t}_{0} h(t-\tau)u(\tau) ~d\tau$$
$$=\int^{t}_{0} h(t) ~dt$$
$$=\frac{R_L\left(1 - e^{-\frac{(R_L + R) t}{CR_LR}}\right)} {R_L + R} u(t) $$

The output voltage in response to a step (where V<sub>0</sub> is the amplitude of the step) is therefore:

$$V_o(t) = V_0\frac{R_L\left(1 - e^{-\frac{(R_L + R) t}{CR_LR}}\right)} {R_L + R} u(t)$$

The output current must be:

$$I_o(t) = \frac{V_o(t)}{R_L} \equiv {\displaystyle{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}\left\{H(s)\frac{V_i(s)}{R_L}\right\}} = V_0\frac{\left(1 - e^{-\frac{(R_L + R) t}{CR_LR}}\right)} {R_L + R} u(t) $$

There is no reactance in the output.

The capacitor current in response to the step is :

$$I_c(t)=\frac{V_0}{R} e^{-\frac{(R_L + R) t}{CR_LR}} u(t)$$

The unit step response of a capacitor in an RC circuit is:

$$V_c(t) = \lim_{R_L\to \infty}\left(\frac{R_L\left(1 - e^{-\frac{(R_L + R) t}{CR_LR}}\right)} {R_L + R}\right) = \left(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}\right) u(t)$$

The equations for a charging capacitor in an RC circuit in response to a DC step are now derived:

$$I_c(t) = C\frac{dV_c(t)}{dt}$$
$$= C\frac{d[V_0\left(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}\right)u(t)]}{dt}$$
$$= \frac{V_0}{R} e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} u(t) $$

The current flowing via the capacitor is always 90 degrees out of phase with the voltage on the capacitor, but if there is a resistor, this current is not 90 degrees out of phase with the input voltage but is still 90 degrees out of phase with the capacitor voltage.

Finally we get to why capacitive reactance varies with frequency i.e. why it doesn't have a flat frequency response. It is simply because current is the derivative of the voltage on the capacitor, and as the frequency increases, the gradient increases, namely the gradient of sin(2x) is 2, and so on, meaning the current increases, therefore the ratio of voltage to current decreases, i.e. the capacitive reactance.

Answer (score 1):

Crudely, if you imagine a capacitor as a balloon that is being pumped up and deflated, the faster you do it the more air goes through it.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are only changing the frequency, the maximum amount of charge that can be deposited on the plates of the capacitor remains the same.
Now if we were to double the frequency of the applied signal, the capacitor would reach its maximum in half the time. So the current, by the equation \$\mathrm{d}q/\mathrm{d}t\$, has also doubled.
This means that capacitive reactance, which is equal to the impedance of the circuit given by the equation:
\$Z=V/I\$, has been reduced to half its original value. Hence the frequency of the signal is inversely related to the capacitive reactance of the circuit.